# What is the best way to order css/javascript files using grunt?

Tags: javascript, css, build, concatenation, gruntjs

I am just getting started with Grunt, and while the concat dependency does a good enough job combining files, it doesn't offer any support for ordering the files, such as dependency declarations.

I am trying to get Grunt to work with an existing project. There is an existing syntax that this project was using that looked very similar to Sprockets:

```
//= require           vendor/farbtastic.js
//= require_directory vendor/semantic
//= require_tree      controllers
```

It would be really wonderful if there was a plugin like concat, but ordered the files using this syntax, or a very similar one.

Unfortunately, I haven't found much. Most suggest to use require js, but I have too much existing source to convert everything over. I am at the stage where I really want to get my application working with the existing source perfectly before I go making any structural changes, such as adding require js.

I did find one project called geartrain, but it only works for javascript files - so it only partially solves the problem. It doesn't seem very well supported.

I think I may be faced with coding my own. Are there any alternatives, whether supporting a similar syntax or just a good all-around solution to this problem that is well-known, supported, etc.?

Thanks!